# Speed up curing time for latex/water-based paint?

Tags: painting

I painted a desk with water-based/latex gloss paint that is taking a long time to cure (I think!). It’s been 3 months since I painted, quite a bit longer than the [1 month or so](https://www.glidden.com/inspiration/all-articles/how-long-does-paint-take-to-dry-cure) I was expecting.

The desk is wooden (chipboard?) and had a thin layer of old paint on that I sanded before painting.

I applied 4-5 thin layers of gloss latex/water-based paint + 1 layer primer using a paint sprayer, leaving 24-48 hours between coats. The paint dried between coats.

The desk is inside, in a relatively warm room at home.

The desk no longer smells and hasn’t for some weeks, but does fail the fingernail test and things stick slightly to it when left on for a short while.

The dents from e.g. fingernails do “heal” (disappear) after an hour or so, but I’m not keen to put anything heavy on it for too much time!

- Does this sound like curing? How long might it take?
- Is there anything I can do to speed it up? I’ve been running a fan to circulate the air over it for the past week or two but that hasn’t helped yet.

Comment: Was the paint new and well mixed?  Have a feeling that a total re-do(remove and repaint) is in your future.

Comment: Seems normal to me and I would never use latex there. We have gloss latex paint on kitchen cabinets and it's that soft after 20 years. IMO whoever suggested latex paint for this job should explain this, or be fired.

Comment: @crip659 The paint was new and well mixed. I really hope there isn’t a complete redo on the cards!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica yikes! The person who “suggested” it was me (because of fumes mainly as painting indoors, and lack of knowledge this might happen). For clarity, are you saying an oil-based paint would have been the better choice?

Comment: @meloncholy yeah, a lot of other choices would have been better.  Wall paint is for walls, and has flexibility and softness on purpose.  There are many nice hard paints, but few are low-fume.  My favorite stuff is 2-part and has BPA and isocyanate in the resin, so spraying takes *pro tier* PPE.

Comment: The task of removing faulty paint is enormous, so on a "particle board" tier desk your least bad option is probably to throw it away and get another one.

Comment: If you like it otherwise, you could put a glass top on it.